# Spark Recommender Engine recommending already interacted items

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've started working with Spark on a small cluster to make a recommendation engine.

The purpose is to recommend books that users might like relying on the fact that they have already purchased that book or not.

So far I have two problems:

The first is that the following code will generate an OutOfMemory/StackOverFlow error if the dataset contains more than 5Mln observations.

```
val rec_model: MatrixFactorizationModel = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings,RANK,ITERATIONS,LAMBDA,ALPHA)
val recs = rec_model.recommendProductsForUsers(N_ITEMS_TO_RECOMMEND)
```

As a workaround I splitted users in smaller datasets and now the recommendation engine seems to work properly, but the output contains recommendations for books that the user has already purchased. How can this be avoided?

**Update 1:**

I added to SparkContext the checkpoint directory and now my ALS model training code looks like this, OOME should be prevented now:

```
val rec_model: MatrixFactorizationModel =
      new ALS()
        .setCheckpointInterval(5)
        .setRank(RANK)
        .setIterations(ITERATIONS)
        .setLambda(LAMBDA)
        .setAlpha(ALPHA)
        .setImplicitPrefs(true)
        .run(rdd)
```

Comment: I guess you have a number of iterations > 10 ?

Comment: @eliasah Iterations is set to 20

Comment: so here actually you have two issues, lets start with the OOME. Are you using checkpointing ?

Comment: @eliasah no, checkpointing was not set. I set a directory on HDFS for checkpoints, plus checkpointinterval = 5 for ALS.

Comment: you need to set the checkpoint dir in the sparkcontext and also set the checkpoint interval to break the lineage because OOME might come from long lineage issue and since ALS is an iterative algorithms the algorithm creates one

Comment: @eliasah done, I'm updating the code in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126336/discussion-between-eliasah-and-vektor88).